# JS not working to close overlay page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting with JS and I have a small problem (I think) with my code.

I'm trying to create an overlay consent page, but it seems my YES (button) is not working properly. When press YES, it should close the overlay and show website content. Can someone help me to fix it?

This is probably a small detail, as always.

```js
function openDialog(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).className += "show";
  document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeDialog(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).className = "warning";
  document.documentElement.style.overflow = "visible";
}


openDialog("warning");
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.consent-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.consentpage {
  background: #000015;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: 'Raleway', monospace;
}

.consent-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.consent-content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  padding: 20px;
}

.consent-content p {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="warning" class="consent-overlay show">
    <div class="consentpage">
      <div class="consent-content">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>AVISO</h1>
            <p>Este website exibe contéudo explícito!</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="closeDialog(&quot;warning&quot;)">Tenho mais de 18 anos</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='https://www.webnode.com.br';">Tenho menos de 18 anos</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You just need to preventDefault.  You could also try return false after closeDialog.

Comment: Can you help me with that? What should I change in the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for. I added the `jQuery` and `boostrap` `<script>s` to the `<head>` of the document. I also stripped out all the `white spaces` in the `bootstrap <script> tag`.

You don't need to add the class `show` as it adds itself automatically. You do however need to `remove` the show class and add a `hide` class.

Here's the code:

```js
function openDialog()
{
  document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeDialog()
{
  document.getElementById("warning").classList.remove( "show" )
  document.getElementById("warning").classList.add("hide");
}

openDialog();
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.consent-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.consentpage {
  background: #000015;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: 'Raleway', monospace;
}

.consent-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.consent-content h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  padding: 20px;
}

.consent-content p {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="warning" class="consent-overlay show">
    <div class="consentpage">
      <div class="consent-content">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>AVISO</h1>
            <p>Este website exibe contéudo explícito!</p>
            <div class="button">
              <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="closeDialog()">Tenho mais de 18 anos</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='https://www.webnode.com.br';">Tenho menos de 18 anos</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example content -->
  <div>
    <div>This is some content here 1.</div>
    <div>This is some content here 2.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right, I was on the phone. I edited now to explain. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan86 thank you for your reply. Nevertheless, when you hit the green button you will get a white page with a link on up left corner.. you can try http://consent18.webnode.com/

Comment: @RuiAlmeida Ok, I think I got it. I edited. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Ivan86 thanks! yes, of course I don't want to display your divs but my website. Anyway, thank you for the help! :)